# Running a powershell script from C# ends in error

Tags: c#, sharepoint, powershell-3.0

I want to trigger a site design from powershell. It works here but when I try to run it through c# I get this error:

> Cannot convert value "param" to type
>   "Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPOSiteDesignPipeBind". Error:
>   "Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes
>   (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)

I have tested several versions of the `addScript` string but none have worked. This is the code I'm trying to run. And it works fine in powershell.

```bsh
PowerShellInstance.AddScript("Invoke-SPOSiteDesign -Identity param($paramSiteDesignId) -WebUrl param($paramUrl)");
PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("paramSiteDesignId", "176d2af0-1772-41b2-9ad7-acfceefc8851");
PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("paramUrl", "https://TenantName.sharepoint.com/sites/TMVTest13");
```

Any help pointing me in the right direction is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/developer/hosting/adding-and-invoking-commands), `AddParameter` doesn't work by replacing placeholders the way you are doing it, but instead works by adding parameter/value pairs to the given command as parameters.

Your code probably results in something like this:

```
Invoke-SPOSiteDesign -Identity param($paramSiteDesignId) -WebUrl param($paramUrl) -paramSiteDesignId 176d2af0-1772-41b2-9ad7-acfceefc8851 -paramUrl https://TenantName.sharepoint.com/sites/TMVTest13
```

According to the documentation, this should do what you want:

````
PowerShellInstance = PowerShellInstance.AddScript("Invoke-SPOSiteDesign");
PowerShellInstance = PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("Identity", "176d2af0-1772-41b2-9ad7-acfceefc8851");
PowerShellInstance = PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("WebUrl", "https://TenantName.sharepoint.com/sites/TMVTest13");```
````

Comment: I tried doing that but gave me a new error. {Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters: Identity WebUrl.} So now it looks as none of the parameters is in the actual script code.

Comment: @Bakkers could you try my edited answer? Apparently those `Add` methods return a `PSCommand` object with the script/parameter added but don't seem to touch the object they were executed on.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way doing it directly in C# with Tenant.ApplySiteDesign. It works great see link for more info https://laurakokkarinen.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-sharepoint-site-designs-and-site-scripts/#applying-site-designs-programmatically

Comment: please edit your answer and add more details to it. Your answer should still allow someone else to solve a similiar issue, even if the site you reference goes down or its content changes.